# Drupal 7 + Commerce + Addressfield remove specific <div> from form markup

Tags: forms, commerce, theming

i use drupal + commerce + adressfield and i am cleaning up the checkout-page form markup (at least i try).

i am familiar with the theme functions of form.inc and have removed some divs aleady using this functions but one of the divs i dont know were it is defined.

dpm(); says it resides in  `$element['#children']` but `['#children']` is the whole markup including the div i want to remove.

to be clear: i want to remove the red marked outer div only!

[image]

Comment: That might not be the best idea - I think the 'add another' javascript functionality targets those wrappers specifically

Comment: thanks for comment but i want to understand were all this markup comes from. a check later will show what divs essentially needed. any more comments on this? thanks.

Comment: I'd guess they're added by `addressfield_process_format_form()` (process function for the addressfield form element), might be a good place to start

Comment: inner elements are added by addressfield.module and adress.inc
the origin of the marked div in red is still unknown. i had a look at your function and i dont think thats the right place. but thank you.

Comment: ok got it.
form.inc
function `function drupal_build_form($form_id, &$form_state)`
add there `unset($form['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und']['#prefix']);
unset($form['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und']['#suffix']);`

Answer (score 0):

The user's answer in the comment is wrong. We never want to hack a module. But we can use [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to modify the #suffix and #prefix.